# How to turn off the GitHub "eligible domain" email warning banner?

Tags: github

I was recently granted access to another organisation's Private repository & Secret team on GitHub.

Now, the below annoying banner appears on the top of most GitHub pages. I can't figure out how to silence it.

[image: It looks like you are opted in to receive ---- email notifications, but haven't added an email from a verified or approved domain. This organisation requires a verified email from one of the following domains in order to receive email notifications for organization activity]

I do not have an email address from the approved domains, and I'm quite sure they won't give me one (I don't work for them!). I tried adding a fake email address at the approved domain, but of course I can't verify it by receiving a code. I did not knowingly "opt in" to receive email notifications, but I did accept invitations to the team & repo, so may have inadvertently done so.

I have clicked through a bunch of GitHub profile/settings pages but haven't found any relevant option.

How can I make this banner disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default settings of a repo and a team will make you watch the repo or team when you're added:

[image: Showing default notification settings and turning off auto-watch]

By unwatching the repo and the team, the banner should go away. You can find [all watched repos on the Manage Notifications page](https://github.com/watching).

You can also change the subscriptions in [your profile's notification settings](https://github.com/settings/notifications):

[image: Showing the notification subscriptions settings panel and unchecking email]

Indeed explicitly being added to the repo instead of the org will also make you an "External Collaborator" which are exempt from notification domain requirements.

Comment: The weird thing is that the repo or team do not appear in my watch list! But, if I change both the notification channel settings to "On GitHub" only, the banner finally disappears.

Hopefully the weekly digest email will still alert me about messages on other repos. Thanks!

Comment: I use the app more and more. It's a much better way to receive notifications.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this comes from [Jan. 2019: "Limit organization email notifications to verified domains"](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-01-23-limit-organization-email-notifications-to-verified-domains/), which refers to "[Restricting email notifications for your organization](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations/keeping-your-organization-secure/managing-security-settings-for-your-organization/restricting-email-notifications-for-your-organization)" (GitHub Enterprise Cloud, but the same idea could apply in your case)

You can either [verify your email](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-email-preferences/verifying-your-email-address) (not an option here), or:

> **Outside collaborators are not subject to restrictions on email notifications for verified or approved domains**.

So check if you can be declared as an "[**outside collaborator**](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations/managing-peoples-access-to-your-organization-with-roles/roles-in-an-organization#outside-collaborators)".

That way, you would not see that banner.

Comment: Nice find! I was hoping there was something I could do from my end, but I will ask to be 'demoted' to outside collaborator...

Comment: @abb Yes, that "demotion" should be useful in your case.